# Add link to the newly created entity record using Notify.js - CRM

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a custom workflow activity that creates new opportunity from my custom workflow activity.
I have that activity as an action step. I am using action, because it has an output. I need to get Id of opportunity i created.
I call that action from JS web resource using Process.js. After that I use Notify.js to notify the user that opportunity was created. On that notification i need to have button that would be link to the newly created opportunity.

Here are some parts of the C# code related to the output parameter. Just to notice that part of the code for creating opportunity, and doing some more tasks works fine:

```
//define variable
[Output("Opportunity")]
[ReferenceTarget("opportunity")]
public OutArgument<EntityReference> NewOpportunity { get; set; }

//create opportunity and entity reference(i am not sure do ineed entity reference, or something else for that link)
Guid opportunityId = service.Create(opportunity);
EntityReference OppId = new EntityReference(opportunity.LogicalName, opportunityId);

//assign value to the output variable
NewOpportunity.Set(Econtext, OppId);
```

Here is how i created my action parameter in action definition:
[image]

And here is the JS code where action is called:

```
function toOpportunity(){

Process.callAction("ad_opportunity",
    [{
        key: "Target",
        type: Process.Type.EntityReference,
        value: { id: Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(), entityType: "ad_productsamplerequest" }
    }],
    function (param) {
        //Success            
         Notify.add("New Opportunity was created:", "INFO", "opportunity",
    [{
        type: "button",
        text: "Go to opportunity",
        callback: function () {

        }
    }]);
    },
    function () {
        // Error
        alert("Opportunity was not created");
    }
);
```

Just to say, it works, action is called, opportunity is created, there is notification after that.  just don't know how to use action output parameter to set the link to the opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to handle the action in a `CodeActivity` class. This will not work. `OutArgument` properties are only accessible within the workflow, they cannot be returned to a calling process.

Instead, create an action with the desired input and output parameters. Then create a plugin and register a synchronous post update step on this action. The plugin class implementation must add the opportunity ID to the `OutputParameters` collection, like this:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    var service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    Entity opportunity;
    // TODO: add code here to build the opportunity.

    Guid opportunityId = service.Create(opportunity);
    context.OutputParameters.Add("NewOpportunity", new EntityReference("opportunity", opportunityId));
}
```

See also this explanation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481600.aspx).

Comment: Is it anyhow possible to do this in Code Activity? 

I have to call this code activity from action, because i have really specific conditions when i call this conditions. I am using action because it has output parameters, and i taught to get the id using that parameters.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to have new plugin just for ID. To register post create step when Opportunity is created, and to use it just to get id of created Opportunity?

Comment: @MilosNikolic: actions and code activities are two different components. I extended my answer to give a bit more explanation. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

As Henk sad, it is not possible to pass Entity Reference, so I passed Guid as a string in my `CodeActivity`:

```
 [Output("Opportunity")]
 public OutArgument<string> NewOpportunity { get; set; }
```

...

```
Guid opportunityId = service.Create(opportunity);
 string guidSend = opportunityId.ToString();
 NewOpportunity.Set(Econtext, guidSend);
```

After that I used that output in JS:

```
var OGuid = param["NewOpportunity"];
        Opport = OGuid.replace(/ /g,'');
```

And set relation to the new opportunity like this:

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("opportunity",""+Opport);
```

First part of `JavaScript` is in Action call, but not in notification, and the last line is in notification, so they are in different part of the code. Therefore I defined `Opport` as global variable and then i can set the value in one function, and call it from other one in notification.

There is another option, without `C#` part. It is possible to create fetch in  notification callback function and return last created opportunity id. This is easier, but not better:

```
     var contactFetchXML = "<fetch mapping='logical' version='1.0' distinct='true' count='1' >"+
                              "<entity name='opportunity' >"+
                                "<attribute name='opportunityid' />"+
                                "<order attribute='createdon' descending='true' />"+
                              "</entity>"+
                          "</fetch>";


    var Guid = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(contactFetchXML);

    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("opportunity",""+Guid[0].id);
```